# Scraping Marquee Tag in Android App Using Jsoup

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup

I'm working on an Android Studio project and trying to scrape content from a website that uses the marquee tag. I've been using Jsoup for web scraping, but I'm encountering difficulties in extracting information from the marquee tag.

Using Jsoup I've read the Jsoup documentation, but I'm struggling to implement it for the marquee tag. Could someone guide me on how to effectively use Jsoup for this scenario?

Additionally, if there are any best practices or specific considerations when scraping content with Jsoup in Android Studio, I'd appreciate any advice.Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is the same question as the user posted 2 days ago and does not includes [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ChatGPT for solve my doubt, that's awesome here is the code how to extract the marquee text data.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import java.io.IOException;

public class YourScrapingClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Replace "your_website_url" with the actual URL you want to scrape
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("your_website_url").get();

            // Replace "marquee" with the specific tag you want to scrape
            Element marqueeElement = document.select("marquee").first();

            if (marqueeElement != null) {
                // Extract and print the text content of the marquee tag
                String marqueeText = marqueeElement.text();
                System.out.println("Marquee Content: " + marqueeText);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No marquee tag found on the page.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```